# "command not found" when attempting to run shell script with crontab

Tags: cron, sh

Trying to run configure some cronbtab jobs on Ubuntu 18.04 however; they will not run. When I attempt to debug I get the following error:

```
root@ip-171-31-2-1:/home/ubuntu/scripts# * * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> /tmp/file
db_backup.sh: command not found
```

My crobtab looks like this:

```
*/20 * * * * sh /home/ubuntu/scripts/db_backup.sh >> /tmp/backup.txt
*/30 * * * * sh /home/ubuntu/scripts/db_sync.sh >> /tmp/sync.log
```

I've confirmed that the commands work fine when running from outside the crontab script. I've also gave run permissions to both files (chmod +x).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do a `ls -ltra` in `/home/ubuntu/scripts` and post the output. Note: the `sh` in your cron fie is not needed.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 8 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Dec 16 14:33 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    364 Dec 18 14:34 db_backup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root     91 Dec 18 14:35 db_sync.sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Dec 18 14:35 .

Comment: `*` is not something you would type at the shell prompt; it expands all the file names in the current directory and attempts to run the first of them as a command with all the others as arguments. The `* * * * ...` line is something you would put in your actual `crontab`, not at the shell prompt. This is a common beginner FAQ, but not really a programming question.

Comment: @Marc The `sh` _may_ be necessary; it can be removed iff the script is executable (`chmod +x`) and has a proper [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Comment: See the [crontab info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) for common issues. Good luck.

Comment: @Kevin : Don't put such multi-line information into a comment, but paste it into your question, so that it becomes readable.

Comment: It is unclear what kind of debugging you actually did to get the output you posted. From the error message, I can conclude that somewhere (in one of your scripts) you are running the plain command `db_backup.sh`,  without  specifiying an explicit path. I don't think that the error message comes from starting the cron command, because `sh` would have then complained _No such file or directory_ instead of _command not found_.